# C++/WinApi Memory Usage rising when moving window

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

So i was playing around with my test application and noticed ram usage is rising when i move my window to the edges of the screen.

Also at 19mb ram usage, the fonts disappear and the app gets buggy.

However this does not happen when the window is not touching the edges of the screen.

Here is a [youtube video](https://youtu.be/we-ZiIL0_S8) of me showing what i mean.

I think my code is just not very efficient.

Code for drawing text:

```
void drawText(LPCWSTR text, LPCWSTR fontName,int fontSize, int x, int y, HDC hdc) {

    //Creat font from name and size

    HFONT font =  CreateFont(
        fontSize,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        FW_NORMAL, 
        FALSE,
        FALSE,
        FALSE,
        ANSI_CHARSET,
        OUT_CHARACTER_PRECIS,
        CLIP_CHARACTER_PRECIS,
        CLEARTYPE_QUALITY,
        DEFAULT_PITCH,
        fontName);

    //Change Current Font

    HFONT oldFont = (HFONT) SelectObject(hdc, font);

    //Draw Text
    TextOut(hdc,
        x,
        y,
        text,
        wcslen(text));

    //Set back old font
    SelectObject(hdc, oldFont);
}
```

Implementation:

```
   case WM_PAINT:
      PAINTSTRUCT ps;
      HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

      int y = 10;

      drawText(L"Hey, im Roboto", L"Roboto", 50, 10, y, hdc);
      y += 80;
      drawText(L"Hey, im Arial", L"Arial",50, 10, y, hdc);
      y += 80;
      drawText(L"Hey, im Lucida Grande", L"Lucida Grande", 50, 10, y, hdc);

      EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

      break;
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to delete the font.

Comment: Thanks DeleteObject(font); did solve the Problem. But i would like to know the reason of the memory rising.

Comment: You aren't releasing resources after use. Why would you expect memory usage to *not* increase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a usual case of a **memory leak**. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/wm-paint):

> The WM_PAINT message is sent when the system or another application makes a request to paint a portion of an application's window.

This means that the WM_PAINT message will be sent to your WindowProc callback function every time the system wants to request the program to redraw the window. And if you're moving the window using the mouse, it gets redrawn every time the window changes position at all! You can play around with [Control Spy v2.0](http://web.archive.org/web/20140927165250if_/http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/3/1/a315b133-03a8-4845-b428-ec585369b285/ControlSpy.msi) to see that this is indeed the case.

Either way, you're creating a new font every time the window needs to be redrawn for *any* reason. Such as when it gets moved even a little bit. This way, the memory usage will increase fast. Whereas if you delete the font using [DeleteObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-deleteobject) after applying it to the text, it deallocates the font from memory, so no real memory increase is noticeable.

Comment: This is not just a memory leak. It is a resource leak. Different objects are allocated from different memory. While the process heap is usually available in exuberant amounts, GDI objects (like fonts) [are allocated from a heap *far* more limited](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2010/03/31/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-user-and-gdi-objects-part-2/) in size.